# Как обратиться к дочернему элементу на странице?

Tags: javascript

На странице имеется поле для ввода и рядом его название, мне нужно через консоль браузера ввести значение в это поле, например, так:  document.getElementById('1234').value = 5, но в моем случае id динамичный, подскажите как отталкиваясь от наименования, найти объект нужного мне поля?

Ввести значение необходимо в элемент с id = "1234", хочу отталкиваться от поля с текстом "Введите значение"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/document

Comment: Подскажите я в правильном направлении?) //label[text()='ввести значение']//following::input

Comment: Нашел способ
$x("//label[text()='Введите значение']//following::input")[0].value=4

Comment: ну если работает все окей а то мне не понятно даже что это такое